# Remove a "*" from a line using sed?

Tags: regex, bash, shell, sed

I want to obtain the first field of each line, but it happens one of them will be a '*' and I want it to be skipped.

```
git branch -vv
```

returns

```
  master 34a8e20 [origin/master: behind 14] renamed yml's
* ss_doc 3ebc755 [origin/ss_doc: gone] PRD configuration
  ss_fix d0f4a4c [origin/ss_fix: gone] Merge branch 'ss_fix' into 'master'
  ss_v   c3b4635 [origin/ss_v: gone] remove composes
```

When I apply the following sed command, the result is the following

```
git branch -vv |  sed -r  's|\*?(\w+).+|\1|'
```

the result is

```
  master
* ss_doc
  ss_fix
  ss_v
```

I cannot understand why it catches the "*" within the matching group. I've tried other workarounds but this is the closest to the goal. How not to catch the "*"?

Comment: Because there is a space, the `*` is not matched. Use `sed -r  's|\*?\s*(\w+).+|\1|'`

Comment: Thank you @WiktorStribiżew. Why did it return the * so, if it was not matched? It's supposed to have returned that line?

Comment: What is not matched is kept in the result.

Comment: So, how to make it do not return what did not match?

Comment: Hm, use `grep -oP '^\W*\K\w+'`? Why use `sed` with the replace command?

Comment: There are so many solutions you may use, another one: `sed 's/^[^[:alnum:]_]*//' | awk '{print $1}'`. Remove all non-word chars at the start, and use `awk` to grab the first whitespace separated field. What do you need exactly?

Comment: I have now what I intended. But the fact of keep returning something not matched made me a little confused. I had the idea that if it does not match, it does not output

Comment: `sed` replacement command replaces only what is matched. What is not matched, is not replaced.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just tell awk to print the first field after the leading blanks and asterisk:

```
$ awk -F'[ *]+' '{print $2}' file
master
ss_doc
ss_fix
ss_v
```

That will work using any awk in any shell on any UNIX system. If you prefer sed, this will work with any sed:

```
$ sed 's/^[ *]*\([^ ]*\).*/\1/' file
master
ss_doc
ss_fix
ss_v
```

Answer (score 2):

Note that `sed` replacement command replaces only what is matched. What is not matched is not replaced.

Your pattern tries to match a `*`, but if it does not find `*` at the current position, it tries to match `(\w+).+` pattern (since `\*?` matches one or *zero* asterisks). Since it is not matched, the `sed` replacement command keeps the unmatched `*` in the result.

You need to make sure the asterisk is matched. As there is whitespace between the `*` and word chars, you may match it with `\s*` or `[[:space:]]*`:

```
sed -r 's|\*?\s*(\w+).+|\1|'
```

Another way is to match any whitespace and `*` before the word chars:

```
sed -r 's|[*[:space:]]*([[:alnum:]_]+).*|\1|'
          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Or, use a PCRE pattern with `grep` to only match what you need:

```
grep -oP '^\W*\K\w+'
```

Or, remove any non-word chars at the start and `awk` out the first field:

```
sed 's/^[^[:alnum:]_]*//' | awk '{print $1}'
```

See the [online demo](http://rextester.com/UEPMX22190).

Comment: You never need sed when you're using awk. `sed 's/^[^[:alnum:]_]*//' | awk '{print $1}'` can be written as just one command `awk '{sub(/^[^[:alnum:]_]*/,""); print $1}'`. btw `-r` only works in GNU sed, change it to `-E` and it'll work in GNU sed and BSD/OSX sed.